# How to continuously update baseline coverage file that's passed to genhtml?

Tags: gcc, clang, code-coverage, lcov, genhtml

The latest version of [genhtml](https://man.archlinux.org/man/genhtml.1.en) provides a differential coverage report. ie it can tell you stats like if code in the previous version that was "covered" is now "uncovered" and vice versa. To make this work, you need to pass a baseline coverage file to `genhtml` that tells it the current state of coverage of your codebase. When someone adds a new commit to your codebase, `genhtml` uses the baseline file and the current state of coverage to give you differential stats like the one I mentioned above.

But once new changes have been added to the codebase, the baseline file is now stale and needs to be updated to the latest coverage state of the codebase. As you can see, you need to do this every time new code changes are made.

I don't want developers to be bothered by updating this baseline file every time they make new changes. I am thinking of automating updating of the baseline file via Github actions once every week or so. But wanted to see if someone has a better idea or does `genhtml` itself has a mechanism to avoid having to update the baseline file on every code change.